# Incremento em laço For

Tags: php, loop, estilo-de-codificação

Preciso de uma contagem que vá de 1 até 24, mas nessa ordem:

1,9,17,2,10,18,3,11,19,4,12,20,5,13,21,6,14,22,7,15,23,8,16,24

Fiz dessa forma, porém queria algo mais "elegante".

```
for($x=1;$x<9;$x++){
    echo $x.' '.($x+8).' '.($x+16);
}
```

O que poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não consegui identificar nenhum padrão na sequência que pudesse facilitar sua criação. O mais próximo que cheguei foi fazendo:

```
foreach (range(0, 23) as $i)
    echo ($i*8 + 1) % 23, ' ';
```

Mas a saída é:

```
1 9 17 2 10 18 3 11 19 4 12 20 5 13 21 6 14 22 7 15 0 8 16 1
```

Obviamente falhando quando o valor de saída deveria ser 23 ou 24, visto que o termo geral utilizado jamais retornará um valor maior que 22, isto é, funcionou para 91,67% da sequência.

Porém, aproveitando a sua lógica, se precisar iterar sobre esses valores, convém definir um gerador:

```
function sequencia() {
    foreach (range(1, 8) as $i) {
        yield $i;
        yield $i + 8;
        yield $i + 16;
    }
}
```

Desta forma você poderá aproveitar os valores retornados - ao invés de apenas impressos na tela:

```
foreach(sequencia() as $i)
    echo $i, ' ';
```

Gerando:

```
1 9 17 2 10 18 3 11 19 4 12 20 5 13 21 6 14 22 7 15 23 8 16 24
```

Se gostar de uma pegada mais funcional:

```
function sequencia()
{
    return array_reduce(
        array_map(
            function ($x, $y, $z) {
                return [$x, $y, $z];
            },
            ...array_chunk(range(1, 24), 8)
        ), 
        "array_merge",
        []
    );
}
```

O resultado será exatamente a sequência desejada, mas ao meu ver, é adicionar complexidade sem motivos. Como o Maniero disse, *elegância* é relativo.

Answer (score 1):

Elegância é inerentemente subjetivo. Eu vou dizer que não há forma mais elegante, salvo o fato que o código poderia ser mais espaçado para se tornar mais legível.

Me parece ser o objetivo do exercício. Mas tem quem diria que para este casos específico, nesta linguagem o mais elegante é não usar um laço e sim fazer um `echo` com todos os dados. Ainda que provavelmente seria contra o que pede o exercício (embora eu acho que seja comum exercícios serem mal definidos e não disserem que não pode usar uma laço, ou pedir para fazer no menor número de linhas possível, que novamente pode ser mais interessante sem o `for`, mas com a menor quantidade de caracteres o `for` pode ser melhor, mas ainda assim eu acho que não deveria contar caracteres que dão legibilidade.

Claro poderia fazer com recursão, tem quem dirá que é mais elegante.

Tem alguns pequenos detalhes que poderia ser diferente, mas não acho que vale o esforço, ficaria mais esquisito.

Só noite que a vírgula não foi usada. Ou não produz o resultado esperado ou o enunciado do problema não está bem definido acima.